# Abort slow NFS operation

Tags: linux, ssh, nfs

I'm connected to a server via ssh, on that server I'm trying to access an NFS directory. However, due to connection issues, basic commands like `ls` sometimes, but not alway, take forever to complete inside this directory. Is there a better way to abort such commands than terminating and reopening the ssh connection? Sending `SIGING` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: This might slow things down even worse, but look into using `screen` or `tmux` so you’ll have another shell from which you can issue a `kill` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After kernel version 2.6.25, the only way to stop processes hanging on unreachable NFS mounts is SIGKILL, i.e. `kill -9`.

Before that kernel version, it used to depend on mount options used: with options `hard,nointr` the processes would have been non-interruptible, and with `hard,intr` it would have been possible to interrupt a NFS-hung process with SIGINT.

In kernel 2.6.25, it was recognized that processes being totally unkillable is generally highly undesirable, so the entire `intr/nointr` mount option pair was made non-operational and `intr` was made the standard operating mode. At the same time, the signal requirement was tightened to SIGKILL to make it obvious that killing a process in such a state should only be done after a careful consideration.

Inherently read-only processes such as `ls` should always be safe to kill, but if the process is writing something into a file located in a NFS filesystem, gets hung on unreachable NFS server, and you kill it, the target file may be in an incoherent state afterwards and may need some application-specific recovery actions.

With options `soft,timeo=<number of deciseconds>`, the operation would automatically fail with an error after the specified time was elapsed, but this has a potential of causing data integrity issues. For example, if a program was accessing a NFS-based file with a write-enabled  `mmap(2)`, and a write operation failed, there would have been no way to report the error back to the program, nor even a deterministic way to prevent the program from proceeding onwards, unless/until the program called `munmap(2)` or `msync(2)`. So, either the data in memory and the data on disk would have been out of sync, or the memory-mapped data would have to silently revert itself to the pre-write state behind the program's back... **neither** of those is a good option, and **that** is why the NFS mount option `soft` is generally not recommended.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. Thanks for explaining this in so much detail.